# sys.excepthook? I want to show a custom 500 error page for uncaught exceptions

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django and want to display a custom 500 error page for uncaught exceptions. How do I do that? I'm worried that the app is just showing a blank page when an uncaught server error occurs.

Currently I have this snippet in sitecustomize.py

```
import sys

def info(type, value, tb):
   if (#hasattr(sys, "ps1") or
       not sys.stderr.isatty() or
       not sys.stdin.isatty()):
       # stdin or stderr is redirected, just do the normal thing
       original_hook(type, value, tb)
   else:
       # a terminal is attached and stderr is not redirected, debug 
       import traceback, pdb
       traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
       print
       pdb.pm()
       #traceback.print_stack()

original_hook = sys.excepthook
if sys.excepthook == sys.__excepthook__:
     # if someone already patched excepthook, let them win
     sys.excepthook = info
```

Right now I am raising UnreadablePostError and not catching it in the post login action. Doing this is giving me a white page with "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." text. I've tried just logging the error by using this snippet instead of the  original_hook in the info function:

```
import logging
logger.error("Uncaught exception", exc_info=(type, value, tb))
```

The Python interpreter doesn't seem to be using the sys.excepthook. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show users custom 500 error html page you can use [handler500](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views).
If you want to log exceptions then you don't need to intercept all exceptions manually - you can just add [logging settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples).

P.S.: I'd recommend you to check out [sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry) for handling errors from multiple production servers so you won't need to check logs or create any kind of notifications.